# Convert int Value to a RGB Color

Tags: colors, int, rgb

I'm relatively new to Programming and im trying to make a Puzzle Boardgame in Java, and I want to make the tokens you have to move in different colors.
The Position and Number of the tokens is saved in this array:

`{
    {2,1,1,3},
    {2,1,1,3},
    {4,6,6,5},
    {4,7,8,5},
    {9,0,0,10}
}`

So now my question is, how can i convert these numbers into RGB color values, that are easily distinguishable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the java.awt.Color class for Rgb and int Stuff.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

You can use:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)

for getting an Color from an int or

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20int,%20int)

for creating an Color based on an 
rgb value.

You can use an Random method for generate the Colors.

Or choose some Colors and store them in an Array and pick them randomly for any Token.

Edit (Response to Comment):

You can take an hashmap for this.
So save the token number as the key and the Color as the Value:

```
HashMap<Integer,Color> map = new HashMap<Integer,Color>();
```

and than just simple write an Method like this to get the Color of the Token:

```
private Color getColor(int tokenNumber){
    if(!map.containsKey(tokenNumber)){
        map.put(tokenNumber, createColorForToken(tokenNumber));
    }
    return map.get(tokenNumber);

}
```

sorry for bad English :P

Comment: And how do i get the code to color every token with the number 2 in the same color?

Comment: Look answer.
I added some Code example for you.